# react-router-dom <routes> not rendering anything in localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to use  to render different components based on the URL. My code is in the image. For some reason localhost:3000 is not rendering anything except for  when it is loaded up.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />

          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={<Landing />}>
              <Route exact path="/register" component={<Register />} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={<Login />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the incorrect prop to render the components into the routes. In v6 the `Route` components all use only an `element` prop. This is a breaking change between v5 that had `component`, `render`, and `children` props.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Landing />}>
    <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
    <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-routes-not-rendering-anything-in-localhost3000]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing else worked for me but this. If there is something like the following in your `index.js`:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

remove the `<React.StrictMode>` element and the rendering will work.